# python - не получается утилизировать все ядра по максимому

Tags: python, windows, многопоточность, multiprocessing

Cтолкнулся с проблемой максимальной утилизации ядер при использовании многопроцессорной обработки на 64-битном питоне.

В коде есть 2 места, где я использую многопроцессорность. Код на самом деле довольно ресурсоемкий. Я пытался использовать функцию «map» в пуле процессоров в соответствии с документацией на простых примерах, и это работало, я увидел, что скачки загрузки процессора достигли 99%. А этот реальный код, тем не менее, держит утилизацию на уровне 20%, хотя использует все ядра. На данный момент запущен уже сутки (даже 4 инстанса с разными параметрами), очевидно, что есть много вычислительной работы, но что-то не дает использовать ресурсы по максимому. Похоже, что сам Windows что-то там тоже контроллирует (на машине ничего больше не запущено). Что это может быть? Идея-то в том, чтобы оно загрузилось на 99% и вычислило задачи быстрее.

2 места в коде, где я запускаю многопроцессорность

```
with Pool() as p:
    p.map(fdas_and_digitize, Reports)

with Pool() as p:
    p.map(PnL, files_periods) # this executes in parallel now
```

Вот полный исходный код https://pastebin.com/PnPFUxeL

Windows Server 2016, 64-битная, 24 ядра

C: \ Users \ Администратор> python --version Python 3.7.1
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Думаю надо какой нибудь прифилировщик использовать что бы посмотреть какие участки кода сколько времени занимают. Может у вас расчет идет быстро, а вот на чтение файлов уходит много времени. Ведь если вы в несколько потоков читаете с диска файлы, то это дольше, чем чтение тех же файлов одним потоком. И потоки находятся в ожидании данных от диска.

Comment: Функцию «write2mysql» надо переписать - открывать соединение к БД, делать “commit” и закрывать соединение с БД для __каждой__ строки - непростительное расточительство ресурсов. Я бы весь код переписал с использованием Pandas и векторизированной обработкой данных вместо циклов.

Comment: MaxU, тоесть он не может параллелить потомучто код не гомогенный? Но вопрос все ж в том, почему 20% только утил а не все 90?

Comment: похоже @Mike прав и узким местом у вас является I/O - это может быть как чтение исходных файлов так и запись в MySQL. Но, как вам уже посоветовали, правильнее будет сделать профайлинг. Причем есть смысл сделать отдельно профайлинг для версии без распараллеливания.  Библиотека Pandas умеет эффективно читать / писать табличные данные из / в файлов различных форматов и из БД. Кроме того она идеально подходит для обработки данных табличного вида.

Comment: коллеги, но у меня исходные файлы один раз читаются и все заранее, потом кладутся в json сериализованый numpy массив в значение ключа в redis, и доступ к ним потом через прочтение значения ключа, и рассериализацию... сделал поправку, чтобы в MySQL один раз писалось, но пока не помогло. ушел курить про векторизацию.

Comment: @EdwardSamokhvalov, создайте новый вопрос, опишите в нем как нужно обработать файлы и укажите ссылку на несколько входных файлов и на результирующий (на основе входных файлов), чтобы можно было сверять ответы. Я бы попробовал набросать решение когда будет свободное время. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060)

Comment: всё верно, убрал redis, IO, добавил векторизацию с numpy, разбил на блоки и закодил с ufuncs, утилизация стала 99%! спасибо всем.